# How to upload Excel file to AWS RDS

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-rds

I was trying to upload Excel file to AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server.

Here is what I did:

1. Create an AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server
2. Connect AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server from local Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
3. Import Excel file to locally to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

At this point, the tables are successfully showing in my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

How do I know if the AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server is as synchronized/same/updated as the my local Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

In other words how do I know if I upload the Excel file/tables successfully to AWS RDS?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't Management Studio simply act as a front-end to the database? Are you saying that Management Studio might be running its own database?

Comment: SSMS is just a client application, it doesn't store any data itself. If you can select the data from a table via SSMS then the data is actually residing on the SQL Server instance.

Comment: So what u trying to say is that, if i import an excel file into SSMS, it will automatically import that excel file into aws sql server, correct? I don't have to do anything to synchronize/update click in SSMS, right? Thank you